# Append Excel Ranges to Different Workbook

Tags: excel, powershell

I've done a lot of looking around and couldn't find something close enough to what I'm looking for.

I am using PowerShell to iterate through thousands of spreadsheets that are mostly similar but have small differences here and there. Also, it is not using traditional headers at the top of the sheet because of keys and directions (not my work, can't change it). Therefore, there are groups of columns floating around anywhere in the sheet. There are merged header columns, along with sub-columns beneath these headers. [Picture for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1oSq.jpg) These sections could have more columns also. I am only pulling information in sub-columns, not the merged one.

I am able to get the data range that I want, but I am having a hard time outputting the data to a new Workbook. These ranges I am also pulling are weird because of the way the sheet is set up. (ex `$worksheet.Range("J14", "L40")`

So I have a `foreach` loop that goes through each file and grabs the data I need and I store it in a variable like this:

```
$dataRange = $workSheet.Range($startCell, $endCell)
```

My question here is, how do I keep appending all of the rows from this specific ComObject into a different Workbook? I've been trying to loop through each cell's Text property but it keeps printing it all down the first column of the new Workbook.

Full Script:

```
."C:\Users\q1424360\Desktop\FunctionLibrary.ps1"

#$ErrorActionPreference= 'silentlycontinue'

#File Locations
$tempLocation = "C:\Users\q1424360\Desktop\Final\US"
$targetlocation = "C:\Users\q1424360\Desktop\Final\Test.xlsx"
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$excel.visible = $false
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

#Get all files in directory recursively
Write "Loading Files..."

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $tempLocation -Recurse | Where { 
!$_.PSisContainer } | Sort name
foreach ($file in $files) {
$workBook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file.FullName)
Write-Host -NoNewline "Working on " $file.Name
Write-Host

#Starts at 2 b/c of cache
for ($i = 2; $i -lt $workBook.Worksheets.Count + 1; $i++) {
    $workSheet = $workBook.Worksheets.Item($i)

    ##Get User Account Type & Access Right Information column, find merge 
    column length, get all sub-columns

    $localAdminCol = $workSheet.UsedRange.Find("User Account Type & Access 
    Right Information")
    $accessMergeLength = $localAdminCol.MergeArea.Columns.Count;

    #Logic for finding start cell of range
    $accessStartCol = Convert-NumberToA1($localAdminCol.Column)
    $accessStartRow = $localAdminCol.Row + 2
    $startCell = "$($accessStartCol)$($accessStartRow)"

    #Logic for finding end cell of range
    $endCol = $localAdminCol.Column + $accessMergeLength - 1
    $accessEndCol = Convert-NumberToA1($endCol)
    #Hardcoded for 100 rows down
    $usedRowCount = 
    $excel.WorksheetFunction.CountA($workSheet.Range($accessStartCol + 
    $accessStartRow + ":" + $accessStartCol + "100")) - 1
    $accessEndRow = $accessStartRow + $usedRowCount
    $endCell = "$($accessEndCol)$($accessEndRow)"

    #The actual range that will be pulled for this area
    $dataRange = $workSheet.Range($startCell, $endCell)

    #$dataRange | Out-File $targetlocation -Append -Encoding ASCII
    Release-Ref($workSheet)
    Release-Ref($workBook)
}
$workBook.Close()
$excel.Quit()

}
Write "Files Loaded."

#Release all Com objects stored
Release-Ref($excel)
```

Comment: Well, you need to use Excel API to copy&paste data regions, and note that Excel should be a single instance with several open workbooks. Please provide some code, maybe there is a flaw elsewhere.

Comment: @Vesper I've added the full script above. I am only using a single instance of Excel with multiple workbooks as you mentioned.